# MacOS "open" syscall returns 2 instead of a negative number in the case the file doesn't exist

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, abi

Consider this assembly code on x86-64 MacOS:

```
global start
section .text
    start:
        mov rax, 0x02000005 ; MacOS syscall: "open"
        mov rdi, filename   ; open; 1st parameter: file path
        mov rsi, 0          ; open; 2nd parameter: flags
        mov rdx, 0          ; open; 3rd parameter: in case of a newly created file, the file permissions
        syscall
        mov rdi, rax        ; set the return value of open (the file descriptor or the error code)
                            ; as the 1st parameter of the next syscall, "exit": exit status
        mov rax, 0x02000001 ; MacOS syscall: "exit"
        syscall

section .data
    filename: db "doesntexist", 0 ; a non-existing filename
```

It calls just "open" and then "exit", returning the return code of the "open" syscall as the exit status.

For convenience, here's how to assemble and run it: `nasm -f macho64 simple.asm && ld simple.o -static -o simple && ./simple`. And right after running, to see the exit status: `echo $?`.

What surprises me, is that as of MacOS Monterey (12.2.1（21D62）), this program prints out `2` instead of a negative number converted to the exit status range. (Returning `-1` would generate the exist status of `255`; this is easy to test, tweaking above code, but I also made separately sure that the `rax` register on return is actually in the low positive range.) "open" is supposed to return a file descriptor or an error code, but a positive number corresponding to the file descriptor of `stderr` doesn't look like either of those. To be sure that the code above is working just `touch doesntexist`, run again and see that it returns a valid file descriptor of `3`.

Officially, MacOS supports only doing syscalls through the OS-provided API, not directly via an ABI like this. Is this just a case of undocumented/unstable behaviour of MacOS syscalls, or do I have a mistake or a misunderstanding somewhere?

**Edit:** In the comments, there was a valid concern of whether the return value was turned from negative to positive in the conversion from the return value of the syscall (a 64-bit register) to the exit status of the process (0-255). Here's an attempt to prove that this isn't the case:

```
global start
section .text
    start:
        mov rax, 0x02000005 ; MacOS syscall: open
        mov rdi, filename   ; open; 1st parameter: file path
        mov rsi, 0          ; open; 2nd parameter: flags
        mov rdx, 0          ; open; 3rd parameter: in case of a newly created file, the file permissions
        syscall
        cmp rax, 0          ; if the result was negative or positive
        mov rax, 0x02000001 ; MacOS syscall: exit
        jg ok               ; if the result was positive, jump to "ok" and return 99
    error:
        mov rdi, 66
        syscall
    ok:
        mov rdi, 99
        syscall

section .data
    filename: db "doesntexist", 0 ; a non-existing filename
```

The process returns `99`, which means that `rax` was positive.

Comment: Are error status codes and `main` return values compatible types?  If not and the `main` return value is a smaller number of bits, that will truncate, potentially turning a negative error number into a positive number, depending on the original error code value.

Comment: As I said in the main text, I separately made sure that the `rax` register was in the low positive range.

Comment: (I guess I've better to post the code to do that too, lest I'd be wasting everyone's time.)

Comment: MacOS raw system calls set CF on error, and I think the return value is the errno code.  (Of course it won't always return `-1`, then you couldn't distinguish different errors.  The global or per-thread `errno` variable is a user-space thing.  The libc wrapper functions provide the POSIX API where errors return `-1`.  BTW, on Linux, -4095 .. -1 are `-errno` return values codes, in-band instead of using CF)  Anyway, is `ENOENT == 2` on MacOS?  It is on x86-64 Linux.

Comment: (turns out yes, the linked duplicate actually quoted a MacOS man page which mentions `2` for `ENOENT`.  And Nate's answer confirms my recollection of the *BSD system-call ABI on x86-64.)

Comment: A somewhat meta question: Is it possible for me to answer this question, based on the marked duplicate, now that I have improved understanding of the issue? (Can't find any way to do it from the GUI anymore...) I feel that would be valuable for the people stumbling upon this question via search engines.